# owl carousel slider second image does not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, owl-carousel

I am using owl carousel in magento ,slider is working and first slide loads perfectly but when slider goes to second one slide ,it does not show anything,if anyone take a look at code and suggest something that would be nice  ,I have below code

`

```
     <h2 class="filter-title" style="margin-top: 20px;"><span class="content"><strong>Featured Fashion 

Dress</strong></span></h2> 


<div class="owl-bottom-narrow owl-banner-carousel" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div id="banner-slider-demo-7" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="opacity: 1; display: block;">
                <div class="owl-wrapper-outer"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="width: 4560px; left: 0px; display: block; transition: all 1000ms ease; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1140px;"><div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient

(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/01.png"}}" alt="">
                    <div class="content type1" style="position:absolute;top:30%;left:10%;text-

align:right">
                        <h2 style="font-weight:600;line-height:1;color:#08c">HUGE <b style="font-

weight:800">SALE</b></h2>
                        <p style="color:#777;font-weight:300;line-height:1;margin-bottom:15px">Now 

starting at <span style="color:#535353;font-weight:400">$99</span></p>
                        <a href="#" style="font-weight:300;">Shop now &gt;</a>
                    </div>
                </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 1140px;"><div class="item" style="background:#f0f0f0;background-image:linear-gradient

(#e8e8e8,#f0f0f0);position:relative;border-radius:5px;">
                    <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/05/02.png"}}" alt="">
                    <div class="content type2" style="position:absolute;top:16.6%;right:25%;text-

align:center">
                        <h2 style="font-weight:700;line-height:1;color:#004f7f;border-

color:#08c">SPECIAL</h2>
                        <h3 style="color:#08c;font-weight:700;line-height:1;margin-bottom:15px">OFFER</h3>
                        <p style="color:#004f7f;font-weight:400;line-height:1.4;margin-bottom:20px">Buy 

new digital cameras &amp; <br>get lenses or accessories</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Shop now!</a>
                    </div>
                </div></div></div></div>

            <div class="owl-controls clickable"><div class="owl-pagination"><div class="owl-page active"><span class=""></span></div><div class="owl-page"><span class=""></span></div></div></div></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($){
                $("#banner-slider-demo-7").owlCarousel({autoPlay:true,lazyLoad: true,stopOnHover: 

true,pagination: true, autoPlay: true,navigation: false,slideSpeed : 500,paginationSpeed : 

500,singleItem:true});
            });
            </script>
        </div>
```

`

Comment: all is perfect. are you able to open image link in browser ?

Comment: Hi,Thanks for reply yes ,even if I put first slider  code ,it does not work my site is mrspiffy.co. in

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your site, it’s seems image `file permission issue`. Just check **02.png** have **0644** file *permission*

Comment: No ,it has 777 still same issue

Comment: can you please attach your image here

Comment: it is overlapping below first image ,I think there is no problem with code but still same problem